# Could Panther shark be played face-down defense when summoned by its own effect?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Panther shark](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Panther_Shark) effect is :

> If your opponent controls 2 or more monsters, you can Normal Summon
> this card without Tributing. If you control "Eagle Shark", you can
> Special Summon this card (from your hand). You can only control 1
> "Panther Shark".

[Eagle shark](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Eagle_Shark) effect is :

> If your opponent controls 2 or more monsters, you can Normal Summon
> this card without Tributing. If you control "Panther Shark", you can
> Special Summon this card (from your hand). You can only control 1
> "Eagle Shark".

I would like to know if I can play [Panther shark](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Panther_Shark) face-down defense position from its own effect.

> If you control "Eagle Shark", you can
> Special Summon this card (from your hand).

And also can I summon in face-down defense position Panther shark according to the first part of its effect?

> If your opponent controls 2 or more monsters, you can Normal Summon
> this card without Tributing

To sum up does the normal and special summon allowed by the effect of panther shark allows me to play this card in defense position face-down?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you normal summon you can play in face down

but

If it is special summoned it has to be face up

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, because it specifically says "Normal Summon," not setting, which is a slightly different concept than just Normal Summoning.